# How to preview images &pdf after uploading as attachment in form view in Odoo V12

Tags: jquery, xml, python-3.x, odoo-12

There is ir.attachment model available for uploading URL and files but I want to upload images,pdf files and that can be viewed on the uploading form UI-view.

Is there any way I can do it as I haven't found anything on this related to Odoo V12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `pdf_viewer` widget on the form view definition.

See an example at `<path_to_v12>/addons/mrp/views/mrp_workorder_views.xml`. The relevant code follows:

```
<notebook>
    <page string="Work Instruction" attrs="{'invisible': [('worksheet', '=', False)]}">
        <field name="worksheet" widget="pdf_viewer"/>
    </page>
    ...
</notebook>
```

and `worksheet` was defined as `Binary` (you may add the parameter `attachment=True`) like this:

```
worksheet = fields.Binary('Worksheet', attachment=True)
```

Comment: can you help me in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56113613/odoo-11-valueerror-expected-singleton-s-record

Comment: I'm not aware of a widget to show both, but you may use some library such as imagemagik to convert the image to pdf behind the scenes

Comment: helo @AdanCortes, can you help me to remove the download button on the navigation bar of the pdf attachement viewer? Thankyou in advance

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your message before, if I can still be of help please ask a question and tag me.