# Odoo 11 ValueError: Expected singleton: %s" % record

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

I am creating a custom module where I want to get all the selected employee in the Payroll and send them a default email. For that I am doing this

To show the action button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
      <record id="action_email_payslip" model="ir.actions.server">
      <field name="name">Email</field>
      <field eval="2" name="sequence"/>
      <field name="view_mode">form</field>
      <field name="multi" eval="False"/>
            <field name="model_id" ref="hr_payroll.model_hr_payslip"/> 
            <field name="binding_model_id" ref="hr_payroll.model_hr_payslip"/>
            <field name="state">code</field> 
            <field name="code"> 
            action = records.action_send_email() 
            </field>
    </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

In the model my code is like this

from odoo import models, fields, api, _

```
class EmailPayslip(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.payslip'

    @api.multi
    def action_send_email(self):

        selected_employess = []
        not_selected_employees = []

        for payslip in self:
          try:
            lang = payslip.employee_id.user_id.lang
            template.with_context(lang=lang).send_mail(
                self.env.user.id, force_send=True, raise_exception=True
            )
            selected_employess.append(payslip.name)
          except Exception as e:
            not_selected_employees.append(payslip.name)

        print(selected_employess)
```

But its showing error like

```
ValueError: Expected singleton: %s" % record
```

ValueError: Expected singleton: hr.payslip(1, 3, 4)

Can someone tell me what I a doing wrong here and how to fix this?
Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable.

Regards,

Comment: You must provide the full traceback.

Comment: @NewUser, Yaio asking you to post complete error log.

Comment: @KbiR actually when I am doing my code it actually showing a blank page. Here is the screenshot  https://imgur.com/a/yP3nHLT

Comment: Try use the `@api.one` decorator instead `multi`, and change what has to change

Comment: @khelilimiliana `@api.one` Deprecated since version `9.0`: one() often makes the code less clear and behaves in ways developers and readers may not expect.

It is strongly recommended to use `multi()` and either iterate on the self recordset or ensure that the recordset is a single record with `ensure_one()`.

Comment: I have used @multi iterate but its not working here as I wanted.

Comment: `ValueError: Expected singleton` means that you're calling a function that expects a single record and it's getting a recordset. So, in order to help you, we need to know the stack trace which is printed on the log screen/file. Or you need to debug the caller function.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code snippet,

```
 template.with_context(lang=lang).send_mail(
            payslip.employee_id.user_id.id, force_send=True, raise_exception=True
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to loop the 'payslip' also , like below

```
 for payslip in self:
    for slip in payslip:
         try:
           lang = payslip.employee_id.user_id.lang
           template.with_context(lang=lang).send_mail(
               self.env.user.id, force_send=True, raise_exception=True
           )
           selected_employess.append(slip.name)
         except Exception as e:
           not_selected_employees.append(slip.name)
```